# Epistemic or dynamic usage of 'can'?

Tags: modal-verbs

> 1. We hope this digging method **can** be useful to those workers.
> 2. We hope this digging machine **can** be useful to those workers.

Is **can** epistemic or dynamic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these sentences you arrive at a point where it is really neither useful or accurate to speak of *can* itself being epistemic.

In the first place, every modal verb exhibits some degree of epistemicity in every use. A modal verb marks the eventuality it puts forward as something which *has not happened (yet)*; consequently, it inherently involves and ‘qualifies the speaker’s commitment to the truth of the modalised proposition’—the *CGEL*’s<sup>†</sup> definition of epistemic modality (p.52).

In the second place, epistemicity is not entirely determined by the modal verb itself (CGEL discusses this under the rubric of ‘modal harmony’, p.179). John Feminella points out that ‘The “hope” is the key part here’. I agree, and I suggest we should take this a step farther: it is *hope*, not *can*, which confers the primary epistemic sense on the sentence. What we **can** (!) say is that *can* harmonizes with both epistemic and  non-epistemic intentions.

I am inclined, therefore, to say that a dynamic sense of *can* is primary here. The strictly epistemic sense of *can* is equivalent to *must*, and it is employed in this sense only in the negative<sup>‡</sup>: we say *It cannot be that he has deceived me*, meaning that it is impossible, it *must* be false, but not <sup>✻</sup>*It* can *be that he has deceived me*: *must* or *has to* (or some longer expression) is needed to express modal certainty here, and *can* expressing modal possibility requires *could*.

What the writers hope is that the method/machine will prove to be **capable** of helping. That capability, the core dynamic use of *can*, is *can*’s specific contribution to the sentence.

---

<sub><sup>†</sup> Huddleston and Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, 2002.

<sup>‡</sup> Except in echoic instances, when a speaker denies a previous epistemic use of the negative: ‘That can’t be true!’ —‘On the conrary, it *can* be and *is*!’</sub>

Comment: I had a similar idea on this; this is a marginal area between a clear-cut answer and personal opinions. What's meant by (!) in your answer? I think **can (!)** there suggests a dynamic possibility (what is reasonable).

Comment: @KinzleB  I grow more and more conscious that precise technical terminology eventually runs up against situation where it just doesn't tell you anything useful or even relevant. As for the screamer, it just struck me as - amusing? - that I had to emphasize the very word we are discussing.

Comment: I agree. Technical analysis has its shortcomings. Sometimes I doubt if I'm on the right track of learning English. At my current level, how can I improve my English further?

Comment: @KinzleB Read. Listen. Write. Talk. Engage with the language. She doesn't really care what it's about, as long as you're interested in it she'll teach you something useful every time.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is best understood as "We hope that the digging method **turns out to be useful**". Since this is a speculative version of "can", it's an **epistemic** verb. The speaker is *entertaining the possibility* that we're in a universe in which the digging methods are useful.

Note that modal verbs usually exhibit a number of different facets of meaning, thanks to the natural and wonderful ambiguity of language. But I think the "hope" is the key part here. Again, the speaker is entertaining a possibility of some future state, namely, one in which *the digging method is useful*. That's an **epistemic** usage.

If, instead, it was "The digging machine can be useful to workers", that's a **dynamic** usage: the digging machine has the capacity or capability to be useful. (We're not entertaining a future state there; we're describing things as they are.)

Comment: You are suggesting inanimate subjects cannot be used with a dynamic **can**. What about this one: "Modern launch vehicles have more efficient engines and **can** launch a heavier payload: typically as much as two per cent of their launch weight."?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that, only saying that the first (epistemic) case is more likely here. The digging methods aren't doing the work -- the workers are.